# How do I add text to the beginning of a file with a new line

Tags: linux, sed, osx

How do I add a new empty line to the beginning of a file under MacOS and Linux?

I have tried the below command and it produces a new line character under MacOS

```
sed -i.bak '1s/^/TESTe\n/' test.py
```

Comment: can you show what output you got? and what is expected output?

Comment: I'm not familiar with osx, but I'd suggest you use the `i` (insert) command rather than the `s` (substitute) command - that way, you should be able to avoid the need to specify an explicit line termination

Comment: `cp test.py test.py.bak && (echo TESTe; cat test.py.bak) >test.py`

Comment: A Linux solution is `sed -e '1s/^/\n/' filename`